# Allow negative decimal input on Android with the nice 3X3 numeric keypad

Tags: android, android-edittext, numeric

I want to allow only negative numeric and decimal input with the nice numeric keypad that shows all the numbers in a 3x3 keypad. This keypad has a negative button, but it doesn't do anything, and I can't figure out how to activate it. The following is what I have, but it only allows numeric input:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/expense_amount"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/FieldNumeric"
  android:text="0.00"/>
```

I've seen several answers already that say to add

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

or to use

```
TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
```

among other suggestions. The problem with these answers is they lose the nice 3x3 numeric keypad and bring in the alphabetic keyboard.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks,
Devin

Comment: InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER is going to help but I didn't succeed in getting just the 3x3 keypad

Comment: Thanks for trying! Upgrading my phone to KitKat has actually solved the problem, but that doesn't really work for others.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for android 4.2.2 (Jellybean):

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

Comment: What about everything up to 5.0+ (Lollipop)?